# How to default UTF-8 encoding in Text Encoding in Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app

I'm using Mail.app.

Often times I would write on reply emails typed in foreign language (Chinese, Japanese), and the receiver will see garbled text (e.g. a bunch of ??? or squares).

The way I solve the problem is: before sending each of these reply email, I go to "**Message**" -> "Text **Encoding**" -> select "**Unicode** **UTF-8**". But as soon as the email is sent, text encoding is set back to "Automatic". On my next email, I have to set the text encoding again to UTF-8.

This is annoying. Is there a way to set UTF-8 as default text-encoding, and not Automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to ensure all your email goes out as UTF-8 is to include a Unicode dingbat or similar character in every message, as part of your signature or otherwise.

Comment: What is a unicode "dingbat"? what is a "dingbat"?

Answer (score 5):

Open Terminal.app and type:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail NSPreferredMailCharset "UTF-8"
```

If it does not work, you can revert by using

```
defaults delete com.apple.mail NSPreferredMailCharset
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work. Tried both, and back and forth, and it's still showing "Automatic"!!

Comment: Did you try to send an email? It didn't change the value on my computer either, but it might still work.

Comment: no it still doesn't work. a pile of squres and ?? still..

Comment: This does not work with the last version of Mail.app (as release in Mac OS X Lion 10.7.1). Unfortunately ...

Comment: works in Max OS X Mavericks 10.9.1

Answer (score 0):

It's really odd there is no "standard"/"normal" way to set the default encoding to a user's choice.

By adding a Unicode dingbat character in a signature is more like a trick. The terminal command solution is not working. Even if it's working, it's very odd for a user to set something like this.

I can't believe Apple lets this happen.

It's the most annoying thing after I changed to use Mac. I have to choose the encoding every time I send an email. How ridiculous!

Comment: Does the email you are replying to have an encoding?